# How to fix "CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT"?

Tags: windows, cmake

Executing Command:

```
MSVS201364bit.cmd && python make_aptx_dec.py --x86-64.win.clhd.bin
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
```

Installed latest version 3.6.2 cmake still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are executing cmake by its final full path name and not symbolic link? Currently cmake won't work properly if you execute it through a symbolic link